# Appcompat CardView and Picasso no rounded Corners

Tags: android, android-appcompat, picasso, cardlayout

I do not know where Exactly i Should Adress this issue, if it is my fault, there is something in the Picasso Lib Wrong or in the Cardview Library.

Basicly i have a `CardView` containing an image (Full Card Covered) and A `TextView` overlaying.

When Running the Code on a **Android 5.0** Device, everything works fine and the Image Gets its *Rounded Corners*.

However if i run it on a pre **5.0** device, the image overlaps the `Cardlayout` and does not have rounded Corners.

You can See a Comparison on this Image:
[image: comparison]

Here are some Code Snippets:

**layout_row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pandaImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pandaName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pandaImage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/photo_tint"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Recycler Adapter Loading the Image:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Photo p = photos.get(i);
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(p.getUrl()).fit().into(viewHolder.mImage);
    viewHolder.mPandaName.setText(p.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: What happens if you set the image as background for the card?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the docs, this as designed:

> Due to expensive nature of rounded corner clipping, on platforms before L, CardView does not clip its children that intersect with rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to avoid such intersection (See setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean) to change this behavior).

See [the `CardView` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) for more info.

Comment: when setting setPreventCornerOverlap(false) on pre L devices, the imageview exceeds the `CardView` and aligns with the shadow.. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @mike.b93 I believe you are referencing this bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77821 my comment seems to fix the issue Pre-L. At least on the one device I've tested on.

Answer (score 20):

As @kcoppock mentioned, this is by design.

Here is what I would do in this situation.

1) You can use Picasso [Transformation](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/index.html) interface to specify custom transformation for your image (in our case - image with rounded corners)

2) Apply this transformation to the Picasso request on pre-L devices

3) Since CardView adds some margin for the image - get rid of it on pre-L devices by calling `setPreventOverlap(false)`

Back to the code:

**Custom transformation:**

```
public class RoundedTransformation implements com.squareup.picasso.Transformation {
    private final int radius;
    private final int margin;

    public RoundedTransformation(final int radius, final int margin) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.margin = margin;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(margin, margin, source.getWidth() - margin, source.getHeight() - margin), radius, radius, paint);

        if (source != output) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "rounded(radius=" + radius + ", margin=" + margin + ")";
    }
}
```

**Picasso:**

```
//feel free to play with radius to match your CardView
Picasso.with(mContext).load(p.getUrl()).transform(new RoundedTransformation(12, 0)).fit().into(viewHolder.mImage);
```

Comment: `setPreventOverlap(false)` is a very important call whenever dealing with card backgrounds. Very good to have mentioned it here.

Comment: great solution! how to only make the top corner rounded while keeping the bottom squared?

Comment: @jiawen unfortunately achieving one rounded corner  effect takes a little bit more work than just calling one API. Usually it takes drawing in two passes. You can refer to similar questions on SO

Comment: @PavelDudka. I found a good solution here: https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/picasso/transformations/RoundedCornersTransformation.java

It allows you to customize which corner to be rounded.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me like this:

1. Replace the `ImageView` with `RoundedImageView` (https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView).
2. Set the `riv_corner_radius` attribute on the `RoundedImageView` to be the same as `CardView`'s corner.
3. Set `cardPreventCornerOverlap` to false on the `CardView` (`app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`).
4. It looks the same on L and pre-L now.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a global solution for that issue, you can use [Carbon's CardView](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon). It correctly clips its content to rounded corners on all devices back to Froyo. See the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below.

**Important:** don't set background for ImageView in XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_target_marry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_target_marry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="Marry"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="28sp"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```