# How do I add a colour to the top of my android cardviews, like in image?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I've wrote a small application, which shows several android cards. But I'd like to be able to set a colour and title to the top of the card like in the image below, so far I haven't found any information online how to do this. So some help would be fantastic :-)

[image]

***(My code so far does not accomplish the above, so far my code just produces regular all white cardviews)***

My code so far is below:

**CardAdapter.java**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<TTItem> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItems(List<TTItem> items) {
        posts.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        posts.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_cardview, null);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(posts.get(position).title);
        Picasso.with(holder.mImageView.getContext()).load(posts.get(position).images[0]).into(holder.mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView mImageView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    @InjectView(R.id.mainView)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    @InjectView(R.id.refreshContainer)
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private CardAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        int actionBarHeight = 0;
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        refreshLayout.setProgressViewEndTarget(true, actionBarHeight);
        mAdapter = new CardAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        mAdapter.clear();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 2500);
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mainView"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**item_cardview.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding= "5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

---

**The only change I've made from yours is, card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"> and removed the imageview(as no longer needed)**

Screenshot of flashcard not filling to half of card:

[image]

Comment: how you set 22 min to accona

Comment: I don't know how, that is part of my question. I'd like to know how to both set a colour and at title to the top part of the card (I apologise, if that wasn't clear)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is (almost) exact layout of what you want. It is pretty self-explanatory but feel free to ask if something's not clear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout     <!-- This is the specific part you asked to color -->
            android:id="@+id/heading_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/teal_500"
            android:padding="36dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_heading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="22 mins to Ancona"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_subheading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_heading"
                android:text="Light traffic on ss16"
                android:textColor="@color/teal_200"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Assigned delivery boy"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_map" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_footer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_heading"
            android:text="It is just an example!"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_500"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have replaced your `mapFragment` (presumably) with `imageView` to reduce complications.

**Update:** As the question now addresses the infamous "round corner" problem, this is actually by design. Yes, it is a big flaw. But the solution (as given in docs [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean))) would be to use `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` attribute (which I don't think does anything good because it just makes card square again).
See these questions for a good reference to this problem:
[Appcompat CardView and Picasso no rounded Corners](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26552372/2591556)
[Make ImageView fit width of CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27394300/2591556)

Comment: The exact color shown in your image is #109D58. However, use these color palettes to help you choosing colors for your app http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette

Comment: I've noticed the green rectangle (heading_layout) leaves white space. Rather than filling the top half of the card. How do I fix?

Comment: What white space? Can you post a picture or edit your question? Have you used exact layout I posted?

Comment: Yes, one second, I'll add picture to the above

Comment: I have edited the answer. Mainly, it is not possible to use cardView with full efficiency before platform 21. If you must need rounded corners with properly colored backgrounds, use your own custom view. I am not a fan of cardView anyway (because of round corner and padding problems)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can change the colour of a `CardView` in it's entirety but not parts of it. I'm not sure how that would even work.

What you can do, is nest a `TextView` with the title within the `CardView`, then colour the background of the `TextView` to the colour you would like. Use appropriate margins/padding for a uniform look. Add a background to your `TextView` and see what you get.

Your TextView is already using the `match_paren`t parameter on your `android:layout_width=""` so you would only need to add the background like so:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF4444"/>
```

To change the entire CardView colour like I mentioned at the beginning you can do it the same way or programmatically like so:

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(COLOURHERE);
```

Comment: You proposal for TextView is not working for Android 19 and below. The background of the TextView does not match the cardview, there is still white color around the TextView. Only the setCardBackgroundColor si right to color all the cardview